# How to replace an alternator?

Tags: mazda, alternator

I've got an '05 Mazda 3 SP 2.3 and my question is how do I replace my alternator?

My situation is pretty much the exact same as described on this site: http://www.mazda3club.com/showthread.php?t=56092

Comment: Depending on which car parts shop it is, they might change it for you. If you have the tools, it shouldn't be a hard job, though I have ran into a few which were a lot of fun.

Comment: It's possible to service most alternators, i.e. put in new front and back bearings, new bushes (in some models), etc. Ask a Mazda technician. It should work out cheaper than buying a new one.

Comment: @JuannStrauss ... at what cost of time though? Sometimes it just makes sense to "get it done". Rebuilding an alternator is not something the average Joe can do ... replacing one is.

Comment: Don't blame me for being a poor 3rd world resident who tries to save money where he can ;) Yes, servicing an alternator takes a couple of hours and requires you own an angle grinder and a bench clamp (or whatever it's called). Or you could pay someone to do it, which would probably leave you without a car for 2 days. In my experience, you usually save about 50% on the price of a new alternator by refurbishing the old one. Especially if you pay someone to do it after hours.

Comment: Thanks guys, unfortunately living in the 9-5 job world I had to make a decision last night and after locating my alternator (kind of under and to the left of my engine block) I made the decision to have a shop do it. If I had more time and another way of getting to work, I would have loved to do it myself. Will change the question to ask how to replace it, rather than if I should. Would still like to know for future reference.

Comment: Wise decision.  DIY auto work is not for people that have to get to work.  I maintain 1 car and my motorcycle myself, but the other car is critical for getting to work, so it goes to the shop for everything other than the very basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I pulled from an online source:

Remove Alternator

1. Disconnect the negative battery cable.
2. Remove the under cover.
3. Remove the drive belt.
4. Remove the alternator duct and heat insulator.
5. Disconnect the alternator electrical connections.
6. Remove the bolts A, B and C. Refer to the illustration for bolt location.

Install Alternator

1. Install the alternator, tighten bolt A temporarily, then tighten the
   bolts in the following order; B, A and C to 29-41 ft. lbs. (40-55
   Nm).
2. Connect the alternator electrical connections.
3. Install the heat insulator and tighten the bolt to 18-47 inch lbs.
   (2-5 Nm).
4. Install the alternator duct
5. Install the under cover.
6. Install the drive belt.
7. Connect the negative battery cable.

Pulled from Autozone.com

[image: Mazda3 Alternator]

Comment: Is this specific to my '05 Mazda 3, or just in general?

Comment: This is supposedly good for the '05 Mazda 2.3L in both the Mazda3 and Mazda6.